# Do I really need an H-Bridge controller in this application?

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, h-bridge, solenoid-valve

I'm looking to integrate a latching solenoid in my next project. I found a 5V latching type [here](http://www.theleeco.com/electro-fluidic-systems/solenoid-valves/lhl/soft-tube-ported-style.cfm): LHLA0531111H

The manufacturer recommends I use an H-bridge to control switching of the solenoid. The have a few schematics [here](http://www.theleeco.com/engineering/electrical-engineering/lee-solenoid-valve-drive-circuit-schematics.cfm#Latching_Valve_Driver_Schematic).

Instead of using an H-bridge, can I just a use a pair of MOSFESTs to control when it switches? Is that even possible?

Comment: "*... just a use a pair of MOSFESTs ...*" is your wishful thinking.  You need an H-bridge for this solenoid valve.

Comment: Thanks, Nick.  So does one terminal need GND and the other +5 volts? And when I want to actuate the valve, I need to reverse the polarity of the 5V?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way or another you need to reverse the polarity of the pulse applied to the valve coil to change its state.  An H bridge is an easy solution, especially because there are self-contained H bridge driver chips that would be capable of driving this valve without needing external FETs.

There are lots of other ways you could do it.  For example, if you had a split (+ & -) power supply then you could connect one end of the coil to ground and switch the other end to either the + or - supply, but by the time you're done with the level translation and so on this seems like far more work.  I'd just go with the H bridge unless I was really in it for the creative circuit hacking and not simply the least effort.

Answer (score 1):

The latch requires bidirectional control for latching and un latching. The only simple way to do that is an H-Bridge. You can make your own using mosfets or transistors instead of a dedicated H-Bridge driver. The solenoid only requires 500 mW, so around 100 mA @ 5V, so any common small signal transistors will work. 4 to 6 transistors, a few base resistors, and protection diodes are all that are needed.